# include Zxing library as jar for android without adding it as a library

Tags: android, jar, zxing

I am trying to create a QR code scanner using zxing library in my android application, i am able to create project by making zxing application as a library and add to my application as library, but for this to happen we need the application to be installed zxing appication to be installed, is there any possibility to use the library as jar file and acess scanner intent without library.

Thanks & Regards.
Nagendra.

Comment: Hope the below link helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268159/zxing-2-2-import-as-a-library-projectnot-jar-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Use ZBar, it's so much simpler to use.
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/
BTW it also supports iOS

Comment: I am looking to develop it for android device, thanks for the reply