# exporting Zxing qrcode library jar

Tags: android, cordova, zxing, executable-jar

i have downloaded the zxing library from github. i want to increase the size of the qrcode scanning window & export the zxing library as a jar to be re-used. How to create a jar from zxing project. I has many folders.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19293128

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a jar from zxing project.

You can add the library project to your classpath directly.

1. File->New->Other
2. Select Android Project
3. Select "Create Project from existing source"
4. Click "Browse..." button and navigate to wherever your zxing project is
5. Finish
6. Right-click on your project -> Properties
7. In Android->Library section click Add
8. select recently added project -> Ok
9. that's it!

From: [How to add a Library Project to a android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project)

> i want to increase the size of the qrcode scanning window

What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i want to make changes in the zxing library for android & export it as jar to be imported as phonegap plugin. my doubt is, where i have to make changes & how to export is as jar to be reused as a phonegap plugin. Am bit confused of its folder structure? should i have to use maven or ant or eclispe(only GUI) is enough to build it?

Comment: @yokks First, just use the "export" option in Eclipse to export it to a JAR (not a runnable JAR) and see how that goes for you :)

Answer (score 0):

For creating jar, steps you needed are:
1- Import your zxing project that you have downloaded to your workspace.
2- After successful import, right click on your zing project.
3- Go to Properties -> Android window
4- Click check on isLibrary option
5- After implementing above 4 steps, you will find zxing.jar in your zxing 
   android library project inside bin folder
6- You can use/copy this jar in your own android project as a library jar file.
7- However, you have to copy assets & other resources from zxing library project to your project as created jar only contains source files & as of now, Android doesn't support including resources file in jar creation.

Hope this solution may be of your some help.